# substitute for MYSQL variable setting in select statement in postgres?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have MYSQL statements performing procedural processing and try to convert these 
statements into postgresql.

Mysql statements in simple version is following:

```
select 
 case when (eventcode = 10 or eventcode = 30) and @ssid < tmstamp then @ssid := tmstamp 
      when eventcode = 50 and @ssid is null then @ssid := tmstamp 
      else @ssid end as sessionid
from sometable
order by tmstamp;
```

The point is that allocating value of current row is possible and that value should
be referenced at next row.

I tried several method including sub-query & inline views. 
But I can't get solution. 
Is there any idea?

Comment: You can access values of the "previous" row(s) using the `lag()` function. Maybe that is what you want, see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html for an introduction. Can you show some sample data and expected output? I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Agreed, it's hard to follow what this is meant to do without seeing the input (as CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements preferably) and some matching output.

Comment: Actually, I tried lag() function. But the problem is that '@ssid' is not sometable's column but allocated column on the spot. So, I think of inline view like "select  sessionid (select .. @ssid :=... ) ", but the "case when" condition is much various than example and dependent each other, it need recursive inline view and can't be determined how many depth.